# Why are all my dictionary values printing the same output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

*edited
My goal is to print a dictionary (word:count) that counts the number of times the names from characters_list appears in line_list. I have tried changing the code but it either prints the value for each different key as 0, or 1011. This is where I'm currently at, printing 1011 values. I am completely clueless and only a few weeks into a Python class (using Python 3), apologies in advance if this makes no sense.

```
characters_list = [
    'threepio', 'luke', 'imperial officer', 'vader', 'rebel officer',
    'trooper', 'chief pilot', 'captain', 'woman', 'fixer', 'camie',
    'biggs', 'deak', 'leia', 'commander', 'second officer', 'owen',
    'aunt beru', 'ben', 'tagge', 'motti', 'tarkin', 'bartender',
    'creature', 'human', 'han', 'greedo', 'jabba', 'officer cas',
    'voice over deathstar intercom', 'gantry officer', 'intercom voice',
    'trooper voice', 'first trooper', 'first officer', 'second trooper',
    'officer', 'willard', 'dodonna', 'wedge', 'man', 'red leader',
    'chief', 'massassi intercom voice', 'red ten', 'red seven', 'porkins',
    'red nine', 'red eleven', 'gold leader', 'astro-officer',
    'control officer', 'gold two', 'gold five', 'wingman', 'voice',
    'technician'
    ]
    
    line_list = []
    with open('/Users/user_name/Documents/SW_EpisodeIV.txt', 'r') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
              line_list.append(line)
        line_list = [each_string.lower() for each_string in line_list]
my_dict = {}
        for  x in range(len(line_list)):
            x += 1
            
            for i in characters_list:
                my_dict[i] = x
        print(my_dict)
main()
```

Comment: We'll need some more details, like what `characters_list` is. Also, what's the intent of `x += 1`; shouldn't x automatically increase as you loop through the range?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Debugging questions require a [mre], but your code is invalid and you're missing input, desired output, and actual (complete) output.

Comment: @Jacob edited to include more- I thought i was using x to increase my count but it doesn't seem that way...

Comment: ***Why are all my dictionary values printing the same output?***: Because you overwrite in your last `for i ...` the same `key` => `i` over and over again with the same value => `x`. Your `print(my_dict)` shows only the last results.

Comment: The edit is an improvement, but all the advice I gave still applies: Take the tour, the code's still invalid, input is missing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is your data:

```
words = ['foo', 'bar', 'bak']
words2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'bak', 'foo', 'no']
```

You could use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

occurences = {k: v for k, v in Counter(words2).items() if k in words}
```

Or just a dict and make `words` a set so you aren't looping over duplicate words:

```
occurences = {}
for word in set(words):
    occurences[word] = occurences.setdefault(key, 0) + words2.count(word)
```